# I need to remove only the third space in my perl code

Tags: perl

I have a file with multiple spaces and i am replacing the spaces with only a single space using :

```
system "sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]\\+/ /g' /home/donovan/Documents/NWPMIK.txt";
```

How can i now go and remove any spaces after the third space?

Comment: Just to clarify: 'abc def ghi jkl mno pqr' should become 'abc def ghi jklmnopqr' then?

Comment: Please show sample input/output. It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Botje yea exactly

Answer (score 3):

This perl on-liner will remove any space after the 3rd space. What it actually does is replace every sequence of at least 3 spaces with just 3 spaces and write the results to a new file :

```
perl -pe 's/\s{3,}/   /g' /home/donovan/Documents/NWPMIK.txt > /home/donovan/Documents/NWPMIK_new.txt
```

If you are looking to update the file in-place, then :

```
perl -pi -e 's/\s{3,}/   /g' /home/donovan/Documents/NWPMIK.txt
```

Comment: I dont want to replace any of the spaces what im looking to do is remove any space after the third space so the any space before the third can remain then any space after that i would like to remove

Comment: @DonovanWallace, yes, that's exactly what it does. Just updated my answer to make it explicit

Comment: @DonovanWallace "Any space after the third" is exactly the same as "replace 3 or more spaces with exactly 3 spaces".

Comment: @melpomene : your are right ! sorry just fixed my mistake

Answer (score 3):

You can use perl's auto-splitting feature for this:

```
perl -lane 'push @F, join("", splice(@F,3)); print join " ", @F'
```

Example:

```
% echo  'abc def ghi jkl mno pqr' | perl -lane 'push @F, join("", splice(@F,3)); print join " ", @F'
abc def ghi jklmnopqr
```

Comment: This is what im looking for